# my domain name to cloudfoundry instance

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

I have just deployed my Grails app on public cloudfoundry(myApp.cloudfoundry.me) and i need my domain to point to it.  How is this accomplished? or what are the alternatives?

Problem: deploy Grails app via cloudfoundry on cloud with my own domain name instead something.cloudfoundry.me

Resources: i have a virtual server Ubuntu with static public IP available.

Goal: have a way to deploy many of my apps each with their own domain names

If you don't mind sharing how you do it today and, perhaps, if you can reference tutorial that would be very helpful

Thank You,

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but [appfog.com](http://appfog.com) is a Cloud Foundry host that supports custom domains.

Comment: @KyleFinley: Not on the free plan.

Comment: @sureshvv You're correct they no long support custom domains for the free plans. They claimed that that removed the feature from the free plans due to abuse. [Please bring back custom domain support for free accounts.](http://feedback.appfog.com/forums/171983-appfog/suggestions/3768827-please-bring-back-custom-domain-support-for-free-a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Foundry does not currently support custom domain mapping. However, this feature is high on the priority list and development is currently under way. If you do a search at [Cloud Foundry Support](http://support.cloudfoundry.com)
you will find a series of posting regarding this issue and some short term workarounds that could be helpful for you and your particular situation.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you eightyoctan! I accepted your replay as answer, however. i wanted share what i end up doing to have my domain point to cloud foundry hosted app

Option 1. i used GoDaddies Forward+Masking to push app on myapp.cloudfoundry.com and then forward+masking on godaddy to have mydomain.com point my app on cloudfoundry....i am sure i am penalized from SEO aspect to some extent but it works so far

Option 2. I also believe the same goal - have my custom domain point to cloud foundry app via Elastic Ip of EC2 as described in the following blog:
http://www.cloudsoftcorp.com/blog/first-steps-with-cloud-foundry-on-amazon-ec2/
Or use Stakato with EC2 that runs on top of cloud foundry from what i can tell. For more:
http://docs.stackato.com/server/ec2.html#vm-ec2

Either way, I hope cloud foundry does get this feature soon so we don't have to make extra steps to accomplish this